# Mapbox GL: getLayer('id') is always undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I created a mapbox layer to add custom pins. It adds the pins to my map. However, when I go to attach an onClick event to this layer, map.getLayer('custom-pins') always returns undefined.

```
export const drawCustomPinsToMap = (map: mapboxgl.Map, pin: 
IPinJson) => {
  const userGeolocationLayer = map.getLayer('user-geolocation- 
  shadow');

  const userGeolocationLayerId = userGeolocationLayer && 
  userGeolocationLayer.id;

  const { iconUrl, iconSize } = pin;

  map.loadImage(iconUrl, (error: string, image: HTMLImageElement) => 
    {
     if (error) throw error;
    map.addImage('custom-pin', image);
    map.addLayer(
      {
        id: 'custom-pins',
        type: 'symbol',
        interactive: true,
        source: 'pins-and-clusters',
        filter: ['!has', 'point_count'],
        layout: {
          'icon-image': 'custom-pin',
          'icon-size': iconSize
        }
      },
      userGeolocationLayerId
    );
  });
};

export const bindPinsClickHandlers = (
  map: mapboxgl.Map,
  handleLocationClick: (slug: string) => void,
  layerId: string
) => {
  if (map.getLayer(layerId)) {
    map.on('click', layerId, (event: any) => {
      if (!deviceMatch('phablet')) {
       map.flyTo({
          center: event.features[0].geometry.coordinates,
          zoom: 16
        });
      }
      handleLocationClick(event.features[0].properties.slug);
    });

    map.on('mouseenter', layerId, () => {
      map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
    });

    map.on('mouseleave', layerId, () => {
      map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
    });
  }
};
```

layerId is defined & returns the expected layerId, 'custom-pins'.
But map.getLayer('custom-pins') returns undefined, so the onClick event is not attached to it.

Any ideas on what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out -- it was an async problem. map.loadImage is async so it has to be wrapped in a promise.